# Conditional TS types for array items

Tags: typescript, types

Seems like this should be simple but I can't hit on the right config. I'm trying to create a type for an array where each index maps the "plugin" value supplied (an enum) to the types for that particular plugin's options. Here's an example:

```
enum Plugins {
   A = "A",
   B = "B",
   ... 
};

const allOptions = [
  { 
    plugin: Plugins.A,
    options: { 
      // misc, unique options for Plugin A
    }
  },
  {
    plugin: Plugins.B,
    options: { 
      // misc, unique options for Plugin B
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

- Each plugin would have their own custom type for their own plugins,
- The array could be of any length and the plugins could be added in any order,
- It could have multiple entries for a single plugin.

The point is, when a user defines the array I want TS to recognize whatever plugin they supplied for the "plugin" property, then validate the options for that array index has the right type.

I read over TS's conditional types doc, but it didn't seem to quite apply.

Comment: Could you give a [mre] that gives us the miscellaneous unique options so that we have something concrete to test against?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB4PDW) what you're looking for or am I missing something?

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, thanks @jcalz! Interesting syntax on the Options line, I'll have to dig into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to solve this but you could do something along the lines of this:

```js
enum Plugins {
    A = "A",
    B = "B"
}

interface PluginA {
    plugin: Plugins.A
    options: {
        name: string
        codex: number
    }
}

interface PluginB {
    plugin: Plugins.B
    options: {
        name: string
        operations: boolean
    }
}

type PossiblePlugins = PluginA | PluginB

const allOptions: (PossiblePlugins)[] = [
    {
        plugin: Plugins.A,
        options: {
            name: 'Plugin A',
            codex: 1
        }
    },
    {
        plugin: Plugins.B,
        options: {
            name: 'plugin B',
            operations: true
        }
    },
]

console.log(allOptions)
```

Check it out in the Typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgNmA5gSxAZygbwFBT1AQSgF4oAiAsgGl3wCETy6zsBfbbVAF2ACcAzAIYBjYLAQoQRHPigAHCagBc4pKjQA6ArTwB7OV2S70KmbPwhBEYCrRdeqRDvPDdAE2AAPFeAgAjPmd2dk4QHgERMXg1EAYzPAUYlWjJTTpnfUNjNFNnWUtrW3tHPPx9PkEskyg-XV04YEEQILYOLgBPOSjdNDRkPwaU9UYhqSgAH1VJdOxXdC4oQTg4AHkDI2qAChgevoHgUbQASgBtAF1GE%20d480TJZMV0LRpzMvXs3NfXgpsoAHJRoQ-i8vrJXB5vFAAIylPDsWSsEF4G6yO7KKbqDR0JHmTIbHJYWHmH4qP5okBQOjAomycq8Sr4lT2MDAInw-CI7BnDhzND1YAaOC6RCbJard7oI5AA). [The option suggested by jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593924/conditional-ts-types-for-array-items/74594014#comment131669475_74593924) is more ideal depending on the level of experience you have as a Typescript developer.